# Output intervals for the optimal subarrays

Tags: code-golf, restricted-complexity

Consider an array A of integers of length n.  The k-max subarray sum asks us to find up to \$k \leq 3\$ (contiguous) non overlapping subarrays of A with maximum sum.  If A is all negative then this sum will be 0. If A = [-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, 2] and k=2 for example, then the two subarrays could be [2, -1, 2] and [2, 2] with total sum 7.

## Task

Output a list of index pairs representing the subarrays that are being used to form the final k-max subarray  sum.  In the example just shown I would like the  output to be `[(1, 3), (5, 6]]`  to show the subarrays as index pairs in the original array.

## Examples:

```
[8, -5, 1, 0, -6, -7, 2, 4, 0, -1, -1, 6, -2, 5, 7, 8]

k = 1 should give [(6, 15)]. 
k = 2 should give [(0,0), (6, 15)]. 
k = 3 should give [(0,0), (6,7), (11, 15)] 

[-3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, -1, 1, 3, -2]

k = 1 should give [(1, 8)]
k = 2 should give [(1, 3), (7, 8)]
k = 3 should give [(1, 3), (7, 8)]

[2,  5, -5,  5,  2, -6,  3, -4,  3, -3, -1,  1,  5, -2,  2, -5]

k = 1 should give [(0, 4)]
k = 2 should give [(0, 4), (11, 12)]
k = 3 should give [(0, 1), (3, 4), (11, 12)]

[2, -12,  -3,   5, -14,  -4,  13,   3,  13,  -6, -10,  -7,  -2, -1,   0,  -2,  10,  -9,  -4,  15]

k = 1 should give [(6, 8]]
k = 2 should give [(6, 8), (19, 19)]
k = 3 should give [(6, 8), (16, 16), (19, 19)]

[1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]

k = 1 should give [(8, 16)]
k = 2 should give [(0, 1), (8, 16)]
k = 3 should give [(0, 1), (3, 3), (8, 16)]
```

You can 1-index if you prefer. You may also output a flat list of indices rather than a list of pairs.

## Input

An array of integers and a positive integer k.

**k will be at most 3.**

## Restriction

Your code should run in **linear time**. That is, its running time must be \$O(n)\$.

Comment: You should put \$k\leq3\$ in bold, and probably also a bit higher, as it's quite significant.

Comment: @CommandMaster Thank you.

Comment: Are we allowed to use other types of indices for the output? For example, is 1-indexed okay? Is non-inclusive okay? Is half-inclusive okay?

Comment: @CursorCoercer you can 1 index but other than that please stay with the way I have done it.

Comment: Shouldn't the first example have for k=2 the subarray containing 1?

Comment: @qwr Currently for k=2  the first subarray has sum 8 and the second has sum 28. Which subarray has 1 in it with a larger sum?

Comment: Oh I see the start and end index are both inclusive.

Comment: @qwr Yes. I realise that isn't necessarily obvious at first

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 484 bytes

```python
def m(r,x):
 b=c=t=0;s=(0,0)
 for f in range(len(r)):
  c+=r[f]
  if c>t:t=c;s=(b+x,f+x+1)
  if c<=0:b=f+1;c=0
 return s,t
def f(r,k):
 p=[]
 for j in range(k):
  n=x=(0,0);i=a=0;g=[*zip([*zip(x,*p)][1],[*zip(*p,(len(r),))][0])]
  for s in p:
   z,t=m([-a for a in r[s[0]:s[1]]],s[0])
   if i<t:i=t;n=z;h=s
  for s in g:
   z,t=m(r[s[0]:s[1]],s[0])
   if a<t:a=t;x=z
  if a<i:p.remove(h);p+=[(h[0],n[0]),(n[1],h[1])]
  elif x[0]<x[1]:p+=[x]
  p.sort()
 return[(q[0],q[1]-1)for q in p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVPRcqowEH3nK3b6lEjogNrbFkx/JJMH9AblqhghvZNrp9/u3U2w4gxJNmfPObsJYP@53albXK@/TQNH1gvPywTWciOdzKtBslzkPIHm1EMDbQd93W0NO5iO9ZyYsEllrxqNUdvA5sOVTm5It069aFKfFnxMrWRermWTFtVG5gn0xn32HQzCJVS6wdJ7MrRS6Vjvz71eyEAnfeynamWN3W2lml1ay@LsxcxyrQot4n5mxdin4IjnmlOTZDyQsSVHuAgnj0xldUjUoaIakFwO6KS1oJhOQEdoV65spas6eal2cpi6bSduU4MHfY36GvVeXpIRaEv73Jvj6a9hO17ZVCq2Q4XoSCZYR8fZ4RR6NwfUeMysPEIlsT3h9nk49Y7x26UqdiaPM5KyglOP53BifTW@PtqDGUCCStSbgOxFQCEgx@gXjlcBcwHLCBRxEI4gEjH7pkWiskUgzMOT/5DxWRCXKJggBdnTSkQqEAjLcV1EGekCdz7yXkaDrCCEaDFfkDCoi4AtblFovcgpeqVpPhpDPu4gJt9/9KFEbDm7L9PxkHyIpiSd6ITu13i64Nvthm8BbN92jhnPJ7sYk2J//7gLseRRcic2T3t8R1/7b8g@4KtBG/w7vp8evK7/AQ)

Probably still a fair amount of golf left in this, but this is as far as I'm willing to take it for now.

#### Explanation

The important realization here was that we can find the maximal \$k\$ subarrays iteratively. We start with function `m` which simply finds the maximal subarray given an array. To find \$k=1\$ you simply call `m`. From here, for any \$n>0\$ to find the solution for \$k=n+1\$ we start with the solution for \$k=n\$. From there we either break one of our subarrays into two, leaving out some negative middle part, add a new subarray, or do nothing. To figure out which is best we run `m` on all the sections between the subarrays we have and an inverted `m` on the subarrays we have, and take whichever adds the greatest amount to our total. So the function `f` simply performs this process \$k\$ times, leaving us with the desired result.

#### Time complexity

The time complexity is pretty straightforward with this algorithm. Function `m` is linear with respect to the length of `r`. For `f` then, we first note that the size of `p` never exceeds `k`, thus for a fixed `k` things like `p.sort()` are constant time. So the only two lines that really contribute in `f` are `z,t=m([-a for a in r[s[0]:s[1]]],s[0])` and `z,t=m(r[s[0]:s[1]],s[0])` both of which are linear with respect to the length of `r`, and thus so is `f` itself.

Comment: Very cool answer